# How can I test if for 3 variables in one if function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a text file called diseases.txt and it includes all my variables. 
I also ask the user for input about their symptoms as well, then assign them to a list.

```
    with open("diseases.txt", "r") as text:
         symptoms = [line.rstrip('/') for line in symptomlist]
         for line in text:
             if any(symptom in line for symptom in symptoms):
                 print(line)
```

This is the code I use to test my variables and see if they are inside the list.
My diseases.txt file also looks like this:

> influenza = uncoordination/fever/pleuritic pain/snuffle/throat sore/malaise/debilitation/symptom aggravating factors/chill/scleral icterus/nasal flaring/dysuria/lip smacking/headache/sneeze/snore

For example, If I write "fever" into one of my symptomlist[] inputs, I get influenza and other sicknesses that include fever as well. I have over 300 sicknesses and most of them include fever and headache and so on.

I want to be able to change "if any(symptom in line for symptom in symptoms): to `if 3ormorevariables(symptom in line for symptom in symptoms):` meaning testing for 3 variables the user has inputed to my symptomlist. any does it but as the list is getting bigger and bigger it shows more results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your `symptoms` is a list of symptoms, each one a string.
Your line is a single string.
Are you saying you want to test multiple lines of the user's input against all the symptoms of each disease? If so, you'll need to restructure your loops so you have all the user's symptoms (call that `user_symptoms`, it'll be a list). Then you can easily loop over either list (`user_symptoms` or `symptoms`) and check how many matches there are.

But a better way is to make both `symptoms` and `user_symptoms` `set`s rather than lists. Then you can just intersect them directly. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: Oh. This makes more sense than what I was trying to achieve, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just change it to a list comprehension, filter out the non-matching symptoms, then check if the length of the resulting list is `>= 3`:

```
matched_symptoms = [symptom for symptom in symptoms if symptom in line]
if len(matched_symptoms) >= 3:
    print(line)
```

If you don't want to keep checking symptoms after you've found three, you could change the list comprehension back to a generator expression, `itertools.islice` all the results passed the third (so they won't be checked), then check if the resulting list is `== 3` or `< 3`.

Comment: Watch out for that -- if one symptom is a substring of another, this method will produce false matches.

Comment: @GaryO Unless I'm reading it wrong (which is possible because I'm tired), that's the same behavior as their original code which they seem to be OK with.